# Visual studio 2015 update 3 eslint Cannot find module eslint-plugin-react

Tags: javascript

After install "Visual studio update 3" and "DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2"

Stop work eslint in all projects.

I not use *eslint-plugin-react* before

package.json

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1"
}
```

gulpfile.js

```js
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['scripts/app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Error: Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

I`ts not help

```bat
PM> npm eslint -v
3.8.6
PM> npm install -g eslint-plugin-react
C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- eslint-plugin-react@5.2.2
```

Comment: Could you try removing your `node_modules` folder and re-install?

Comment: @dhh Yes, I try removing node_modules folder and restore project. Problem on old and new projects. I have info about  include "Web Analyzer" (Lints JavaScript, JSX, TypeScript, CoffeeScript and CSS files using: ESLint (a better version of JSHint, JSLint and JSCS)) in DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2. Maybe its is problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create .eslintrc in solution root with rules

```json
{
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "array-bracket-spacing": [2, "never"],
    "block-scoped-var": 2,
    "brace-style": [2, "1tbs"],
    "camelcase": 1,
    "computed-property-spacing": [2, "never"],
    "curly": 2,
    "eol-last": 2,
    "eqeqeq": [2, "smart"],
    "max-depth": [1, 3],
    "max-len": [1, 80],
    "max-statements": [1, 30],
    "new-cap": 1,
    "no-extend-native": 2,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 2,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": 1,
    "no-use-before-define": [2, "nofunc"],
    "object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
    "quotes": [2, "single", "avoid-escape"],
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "space-unary-ops": 2
  }
}
```

Or modify "c:\Users....\.eslintrc"

I don`t uderstand what is

"plugins": [ "react" ]

Comment: It's telling eslint to use the plugin you installed so you can set up rules for React code.